# Graphically simulate physical impact of two particles in java

Tags: java, physics

I would like to write a program using Java that simulates a impact between two balls.

From an online tutorial I copied and modified this following first draft.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class grafico extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
    int x1 = 0;
    int x2 = 0;
    int velX1 = 1;
    int velX2 = 1;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x1, 160, 10, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x2, x2, 10, 10);
        tm.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (x1 < 0 || x1 > 500) {
            velX1 = -velX1;
        }
        x1 = x1 + velX1;

        if (x2 < 0 || x2 < 350) {
            velX2 = -velX2;
        }
        x2 = -x2 + velX2;
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        grafico t = new grafico();
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("Tutorial");
        jf.setSize(600, 400);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(t);
    }
}
```

In the implementation of this program I do not want to use applets online.

The first thing I want to change about this program is the following.

The balls don't interfere with each other, but I want them to interact so that when thay collide they change trajectory.

I have no idea about achieving this goal.

Someone can help me or tell me whether it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea about a physical collision is:

**We can say object1 and object2 are colliding each other when x1 = x2 and y1 = y2 in a 2D planner system**.

But we know objects have dimensions and we should assume that in our calculations. So it's better to correct our statement about collision of two objects:

**We can say object1 and object2 are colliding each other when |x1-x2| < n and |y1-y2| < n in a 2D planner system, when `n` is for example half of the objects width or height**.

Also in your code you've drawn a square and the starting point which is used in `g.fillRect` is the up-left corner of that square, not the center of it. So you should be aware of that in your calculations.

So for example you can have a `checkCollision` method in your class to check if the two squares are colliding or not each time you are going to repaint.

In the following code, you can see that I only provided a simple checking for the collision, because I'm only trying to provide the idea not the full working solution for you.

Also after a collision depend on the mass of the objects and their velocity and their previous direction and the elasticity of the collision the next direction and velocity can be vary. So there are two much parameters if you want to simulate a approximate real collision.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class grafico extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
    int x1 = 0;
    int x2 = 0;
    int velX1 = 1;
    int velX2 = 1;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x1, 160, 10, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x2, x2, 10, 10);     
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (x1 < 0 || x1 > 500)
            velX1 = -velX1;
        x1 = x1 + velX1;

        if (x2 < 0 || x2 > 350)
            velX2 = -velX2;
        x2 = x2 + velX2;

        if( checkCollition() ) { // only two show the Idea.
            velX2 = -velX2;      // this code is not simulating a 
            x2 = x2 + velX2;     //    collision. You should change it
                                 //    in the future.
        }
        repaint();
    }

    private boolean checkCollition() {
        return Math.abs(x1-x2) < 10 && Math.abs(160-x2) < 10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        grafico t = new grafico();
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("Tutorial");
        jf.setSize(600, 400);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(t);
        t.tm.start();
    }
}
```

After you run the above code and got the idea, you may want to encapsulate the x, y, previous direction and velocity vector, mass etc. of each object in a java object to make it easier in coding. For example you can create a class `Particle` and then it's much more elegant to move the logic of the `checkCollision` method to this class:

```
public class Particle{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private float mass;
    //
    public Particle() {
        //...
    }

    public boolean collide(Particle other){
        return Math.abs(this.x-other.x) < width 
                && Math.abs(this.y-other.y) < height; // Just to illustrate the idea 
    }
}
```

Then in your program you can create two instance `Particle p1` and `Particle p2` and in your code you can simply change that if statement into this:

```
if( p1.collide(p2) ) {
    // change the direction, velocity, ... of p1 and p2
}
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You have been very kind. Now I try to develop and continue on your points to get what I want

Comment: I can't understand the reason for the down vote. An anonymous down vote won't help anyone.

Comment: Don't sweat it. It was from Jerrod Roberson, who always down-votes answers to questions he closes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Thank's for the clarification ;-)

Comment: No problem. I've weathered many a down-vote from him.